# How to iterate a df (itertuples) that can perform logical operations based on previous rows in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to extract values from the previous row during the itertuples() operations?

Pseudo code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,3,4],[5,6,7],[6,3,5],[7,4,23]])
for row in df.itertuples():
    if (value of column[1] in [row -1 ])>(value of column[1] in row / 2):
        do something
```

I know someone might suggest doing vectorized operations using `.diff()` or `.shift()`, but I would like to know how to achieve the above via a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up a variable to track the previous row

```
prow = None
for row in df.itertuples():
    if prow is None:
        prow = row
    else:
        if prow[1] > row[1] / 2:
            pass
            # do something
        prow = row
```

---

Or you can zip two `itertuples` together

```
for prow, row in zip(df.iloc[:-1].itertuples(), df.iloc[1:].itertuples()):
    if prow[1] > row[1] / 2:
        pass
        # do something
```

Comment: In this case I wonder if any change of prow will mutate the original df? In other words. Is the row returned by itertuples() a new instance or still a reference shared with df? I believe it is a new instance.?

Comment: You can't change `prow` as it is a `tuple` and immutable.

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I want. Coz I am not 100% familiarised with the mutability (reference sharing vs new instance) of the any operations/attributes from the Pandas object.